# Does the Odoo HR kiosk mode scan badges automatically?

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-13

I am trying to use Odoo HR kiosk mode to register my attendances. To do that, I have printed a badge ID for my employee, in the *Attendance/Point of Sale* section of the *HR Settings* tab (employee form view).

When I open the *Attendances > Kiosk Mode* menu, the template *LoginScreenWidget* is shown. I still do not have a device to scan the badge, so my question is if this template will automatically read the printed barcode when I read it with the device. I mean, will this JS method be called automatically from that screen?

```
barcode_cashier_action: function(code) {
    var self = this;
    return this._super(code).then(function (unlock) {
        if (unlock) {
            self.unlock_screen();
        }
    });
},
```

Can I use the mobile phone as a scanner device in order to scan the badge? The Odoo app does nothing at this point.